# How to match by using partial names

Tags: python, sql, excel

I got a problem with selecting the primary key for match. My problem is as below:

Given two tables, one contains employee name and their employee ID, another one only contains employee name(not in standard format) and related information. I would like to combine them together, but since the names cannot be matched exactly. What can I do?

The tables might be like below:

T1

```
FirstName    LastName     EmployeeID
  Newsom       Tom           001
  Greg         Thomas        002
  Henry        Peter         003
```

T2

```
 FirstName      LastName        HiringDate    Gender
   Tom          Newson Jr.      01/01/2019      M
   Greg          Thomas         01/01/2019      M
   Peter Sr.      Henry         01/01/2019      M
```

From the table, the names are mismatched.

Is there a way to formalize it? And can the name be the primary key?

Comment: Are you designing the table or its already there? It's never a good idea to have a primary key on 'name' as two employee can have same name.

Comment: You will have lots of problems using name columns as the primary key. For example, you can have more than one `John Smith`. But to your question, are you importing data from Excel to a database? If so, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: These two tables are existing ones. I just would like to combine them as one table. I know names are not a good choice as primary keys, but there are no better ways. I could use SQL or Python or even excel to do the matching. But now I just wonder how can I manipulate it?

Comment: Well if it were me, I would combine the tables and keep the `EmployeeID` as the primary key for the combined table. In SQL it's possible to concatenate the `FirstName` and `LastName` and use a "substring" function (the exact functions depend on which SQL engine you use), but first `COUNT` records by the combined strings to assure that your don't have a `Tom Newson Jr.` and a  `Tom Newson Sr.`. In such a case, you will have no choice but to _manually_ fix your data before combining the tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions. If you can alter the table to make `EmployeeID` as primary key and use it as a foreign key in another table too, then that would be best.
Other then that, you could try the below query:

**This sql is for Mysql database**

```
select * from 
T1 join T2
on (
    concat(T2.Firstname,T2.Lastname) like concat('%',T1.Firstname, T1.Lastname,'%')
    OR
    concat(T2.Lastname,T2.Firstname) like concat('%',T1.Firstname, T1.Lastname,'%')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You really cannot automate name matching in this way.  The first obvious issue is that two employees could have the same name, "Jane Doe", for instance.  Then there is no way to disambiguate them.

Another problem is that names can be reversed.  "Is "Thomas Williams" the same as "William Thomas"?

The best you can do is to set up a manual process.  This might take the form of dumping all the names into a spreadsheet and manually choosing a canonical form.  Then, load the database with two new tables:

- `Names` which has the employee id and the correct form of the name.
- `Nicknames` which has alternative renderings of the names.

This is a manual process, possibly arduous.  For large numbers of names, there are definitely tools that can help.  For a few hundred, you'll probably be finished before you can even do a proper investigation into other tools.

Comment: Since I actually have thousands of records in the table. I cannot manually formalize the names, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

    `with t1 (fnam,lnam,eid) as (values 
('Newsom','Tom','001'),
('Greg','Thomas','002'),
('Henry','Peter','003') 
),
     t2 (fnam,lnam,hired,gender) as (values 
('Tom','Newson Jr.','01/01/2019','M'),
('Greg','Thomas','01/01/2019','M'),
('Peter Sr.','Henry','01/01/2019','M') 
) select t1.lnam as fnam,
       t1.fnam as lnam,
       t1.eid as emp_id,
       t2.hired as date_hired,
       t2.gender as gender 
  from   t1 
  cross  join t2 
  where  ((t1.lnam like '%' concat t2.fnam concat '%' or
         t1.fnam like '%' concat t2.lnam concat '%') 
        and
        (t2.fnam like '%' concat t1.lnam concat '%' or
         t2.lnam like '%' concat t1.fnam concat '%'))
        or
       ((t1.fnam like '%' concat t2.fnam concat '%' or
         t1.lnam like '%' concat t2.lnam concat '%')
        and
        (t2.fnam like '%' concat t1.fnam concat '%' or
         t2.lnam like '%' concat t1.lnam concat '%'))`